# Art Translation on Gorgeous Pieces!

Tags: translation, character-identification

I came across a few pieces of Chinese art and purchased them all.  One piece was called 100 Stallions and came in a cool box with ivory.  I have these other pieces that I love but I have no clue what they mean!  I think it would be awesome to learn the message behind them for historical significance to the piece.  Thank you!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Judging from the low-level (artistic-wise) poems, these are not written by a famous poet and would not be worth much. The most troubling about the writing is it used a lot of colloquial terms in a body of classical-style text

Comment: health is missed in the text  without it, wealth, longevity is useless 

Comment: 我不懂作詩也看得出第一圖中的詩文俗氣又不押韻，給我錢我也不會掛出來作家中的觀賞品

Comment: Quote:- "...給我錢我也不會掛出來作家中的觀賞品" HaHa, better don't translate this for OB.

Comment: @TangHo thats pretty funny.  I didnt expect them to be worth much I just liked the image and was curious if the text was something interesting, silly, or what!

Comment: @WayneCheah Oh boy!  I was hoping they would say something silly or tell a story.  I looked up some of the characters on the piece on my own and attempted to piece it together but it did not make any sense?

Comment: @MikeI I wouldn't say that it does not make sense. It's just a bunch of rather trite and hackneyed old truisms. Something like "in old age, it's a blessing to have money and long life, and a good marriage. Fame and fortune is hard to come by, but if you are careful with your money, you'll keep your family wealth ... etc., etc. And the calligraphy isn't all that impressive either.

Comment: The above comment is on the first scroll only. Maybe some of you who do traditional Chinese painting can comment on the rest.

Comment: @Mike -- As for the 1st scroll, which doesn't have a painting, you could proudly hang it around your house, (@Tang Ho's "reservation" notwithstanding), and say it is "Chinese Graffiti" ? :) That way you might, I repeat might, escape any adverse remarks from knowledgeable people and envious awe from unsuspecting visitors. BTW, I wouldn't say the calligraphy is atrocious.

Comment: @WayneCheah It is hanging now!  Chinese Grafitti I like that. haha.  Thank you!

Comment: BTW, the author's name is 洪萬居,, Hóng Wàn Jū, (found at the bottom left corner, above his red seal) 洪 is his surname, and his given name is 萬居; 萬 = Ten Thousand, (or numerous), and 居 = Residences, and so 萬居 = "in / at numerous residences" So, maybe  萬居 is only his ambitious moniker, meaning, hoping, that his calligraphy is found in numerous homes?

Comment: And it certainly found its way into yours :)

Comment: I can't imagine you bought it.